# cakePHP prepared statement not working (fetch all not working)

Tags: php, sql-server, cakephp, prepared-statement, cakephp-2.0

I am using cakePHP and can't figure out how to prepare an sql statement. I've tried so many things but nothing seems to work. I am using sql server  2014.

In the cookbook, I found this exact code for prepared statements:

```
    $db = $this->getDataSource();
    $db->fetchAll(
        'SELECT * from users where username = :username AND password = :password',
        array('username' => 'jhon','password' => '12345')
    );
```

However, when I try to use this code (just to see if I cang et it to work), this is my result:

> Warning (512): SQL Error: Line 1: Incorrect syntax near ':'. [APP/Model/Datasource/Mssql.php, line 749]

and my debug:

> Query: SELECT * from users where username = :username AND password = :password

does anyone know why this wouldn't work? Any help at all would be great, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
$db = $this->getDataSource();
$username = 'jhon';
$password = '12345';
$db->fetchAll("SELECT * from users where username = $username AND password = $password");
```

Comment: This is NOT A SOLUTION TO THE PROBLEM. All this does is superimpose the values of the variables into the string. It is ripe for a sql injection.